# cant convert back to date when using defaultdict to pair column values based on seperate column value

Tags: python, pandas, defaultdict

I have a 3643 row dataframe with three columns, `Device` `Date` and `Level`. It is structured such that for however many dates we have a level for, the `Device` is repeated down the column such as:

```
Device  Date          Level
NY      2018-01-02    53 
NY      2018-01-03    40
NY      2018-01-04    48
NY      2018-01-05    43
NY      2018-01-06    47
LA      2018-01-02    52
LA      2018-01-05    39
LA      2018-01-07    55
CHI     2018-03-01    73
CHI     2018-03-04    92
CHI     2018-03-05    54
CHI     2018-03-07    29
```

I have successfully filtered out levels less than 18, and applied such a filter to my dataframe for preprocessing. After that filter, i was able to group them dates and levels based on device.

I am working to create a dictionary where for each device, i have a paired output of the date and level. I have attempted using the defaultdict, but my date is output as `datetime.date(2018, 1, 2), 53` instead of `2018-01-02, 53`. i did convert my date column into a datetime in order to properly filter my data, but i dont know how to convert it back so that my output is:

```
'NY':[(2018-01-02, 53),
      (2018-01-03, 40),
      (2018-01-04, 48),
      (2018-01-05, 43),
      (2018-01-06, 47)],
'LA':[(2018-01-02, 52)....
]
```

Here is what i have attempted so far, including the filtering ad grouping:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('./TrimmedData_2016-2021.xlsx', engine= 'openpyxl')
df = pd.read_excel(xls, '2018')
df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.to_datetime(row['Date']).date(), axis=1)
grouped=df.groupby([df['Device'], df['Date']])['Date'].count()
grouped_set = set(grouped[grouped > 18].index.tolist())
df["filter"] = df.apply(lambda row: ((row['Device'], row['Date']) in grouped_set), axis=1)
df = df[df["filter"]]
df_grouped = df.groupby([df['Device'], df['Date']])['Level'].mean().reset_index()

#here is where i create the dictionary and things look strange
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
for index, row in tqdm(df_grouped.iterrows(), position=0, leave=True):
    res[row["Device"]].append((row["Date"], round(row["Level"],2)))
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `{k:v for k,v in df.groupby('Device')}`?

Comment: is this to be input after my defaultdict `res` has been created?

Comment: No, you would just read you data into memory: `df = pd.read_excel( . . . )` and then just do `{k:list(zip(v['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), v['Level'])) for k,v in df.groupby('Device')}`

Comment: @It_is_Chris I used your method after `df_grouped` was created, and converted that date column into a datetime and it worked! Thank you.